# How to determine I/O burst in Round Robin Scheduling

Tags: io, round-robin

Given a Round Robin sequence 111*2*3*11*4444, where * is context switching and the numbers are various processes. Could someone explain to me how to determine which of these process has the short the I/O burst?  I'm thinking it's processes 2 and 3 because they have the shortest burst.  Also, could you please verify...an I/O burst has shorter burst than a CPU burst.  I've googling for days and I still can't find the answer or maybe I did but I didn't understand the materials so I didn't find it.  Thank you very much for any input you could give me.